# How to import pretrained network model from Keras to Matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I want to use pretrained FaceNet model in github site, in the following link: https://github.com/nyoki-mtl/keras-facenet.
In this link already had trained model (facenet.h5) file. How can i import to Matlab it, please?

I tried to used any suggestion like that : importKerasNetwork, importKerasLayers and downloaded and saved in matlab location, then tried read (h5info). But i can't imported which i wanted that (facenet_keras.h5) to Matlab.

Comment: you cant realy import python objects into Matlab , you can either recreate the same facenet architecture and retrain or try to call the python model from matlab

Answer (score -1):

You may load it into a python program and then use pickle to export the model into a .pkl file. .pkl is text format so all parameters and model configuration are readable. You may manually enter these parameters into your Matlab model.